# Convert Binary Data File to Text File

Tags: text, binary, fortran, ascii

I have a .bin file on my hard drive.
It's recl is nx*ny*4. Its dimensions are (241,121). 241 in x dimension. 121 in y dimension.
How would I convert it using fortran to an ascii file that I can open and read numbers off of?

So, far I have tried

```
real :: g1(241,121) 
open(unit=1,file=gaugemax2010.bin',status='old',
form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=nx*ny*4) 


open(unit=5,file='g2010.txt',status='unknown', 
form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=1) 

read(1, rec=1) ((g1(i,j,),i=1,nx,j=1,ny)
write(5, rec=1) (g1(i,j,),i=1,241),h=1,121) 
end
```

and it has not worked

Comment: What language wrote it?  Do you have that code?   Do you know that the file contains single-precision reals?  Why do you say that it doesn't work ... that the values output are wrong?

Comment: fixing simple syntax errors, stray comma and unbalanced parenthesis: `read(1, rec=1) ((g1(i,j),i=1,nx),j=1,ny)` .  Obvioulsy h should be j in the second case...   Of course since your array is dimensioned exactly right you could just do `read(1,rec=1)g1`

Answer (score 1):

`FORM='UNFORMATTED'` opens a file for *binary* content. For *pure text* you have to specify  `FORM='FORMATTED'`.

For more details on the `OPEN` statement see here: [Opening Binary Files in Fortran: Status, Form, Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998262/opening-binary-files-in-fortran-status-form-access?rq=1)

Comment: I generally use `form='binary'`. Is there any difference?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-CF76FFDA-FDA8-4710-97DF-2C34725434CB.htm#GUID-CF76FFDA-FDA8-4710-97DF-2C34725434CB

`unformatted` appears to still retain some record structure?

Comment: @bdforbes This seems to be some vendor extension. The standard (ch. 9.5.6.11) specifies that the *"FORM= specifier in the OPEN statement [...] shall evaluate to FORMATTED or UNFORMATTED."*